# 11ty pagation across multiple directories / multiple pagation

Tags: javascript, node.js, eleventy

Im using Eleventy/11ty site generator and I have a myData object structured like this

```
[ {name: one, data: [1,2,3]},
  {name: two, data: [1,2,3,4]} ]
```

And I want to generate a set of paged directories of each, for example

```
/one/1.html, /one/2.html etc
/two/1.html, /two/2.html etc
```

Im able to use

```
pagination:
  data: myData
  size: 1
  alias: test
permalink: "{{ test.name | slug }}/index.html"
```

to generate a single html file (`/one/index.html`) with all the data from the object named "one".
However I cant figure out how to additionally page that data to get the desired structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [computed data](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-computed/) + [JS front matter](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-frontmatter/#javascript-front-matter) to get this to work:

```js
~~~js
{
  pagination: {
    data: "flattenedData",
    size: 1,
    alias: "test",
  },
  permalink: "{{ test.name | slugify }}/{{ test.data }}",
  eleventyComputed: {
    flattenedData: ({ myData }) => 
      myData.flatMap(({ name, data }) =>
        data.map(d => ({ name, data: d }))
      )
  }
}
~~~
```

Comment: Marking this as solved as this does actually solve my question, however I realize now that the question did not totally explain the situation. This solution works if each data entry is a single page, however if multiple data entries need to be on a single page I think this solution does not apply?